# Pip Install Subprocess to Install Build Dependencies Did Not Run Successfully

Tags: python, pip, subprocess

I've tried a few other threads here tied to updating setuptools first, but no dice.

I have a machine that is going to ultimately be air-gapped. I'm trying to get the installation process down. As doing so, my procedure right now included going to the identical working machine and using `pip freeze` to generate a `requirements.txt`

I then on the target machine, put the `requirements.txt`.  I turned the internet on temporarily for testing. I did a `pip download` on `requirements.txt` to pull the packages. I then shut the internet off and tried `pip install --no-index --find-links=. requirements.txt`

It installs the first few packages fine, but then it hits some and has

`
Processing ./ansible-vault-2.1.0.tar.gz (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
Installing build dependencies ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [4 lines of output]
Looking in links: .
Processing ./setuptools-68.2.2-py3-none-any.whl
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wheel (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for wheel
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

This happens for a few different packages, but I cannot find anything that would cause this. Can someone point me in the right direction, as the few threads I've tried on SO and the few Google searches I've tried almost all point to making sure your packages are for the right Python version (they must be, I pulled them from the version I'm trying to install with), and updating setup tools (I did).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `pip download --platform <platform>` will solve you the issue

The list of platform options for the `--platform` flag in pip may vary depending on the specific packages and versions available in the Python Package Index (PyPI). However, here are some common platform options you may encounter:

1. `win32`: 32-bit Windows platform.
2. `win_amd64`: 64-bit Windows platform.
3. `macosx_10_9_x86_64`: macOS platform targeting x86_64 architecture (64-bit). (Not sure of the version)
4. `manylinux1_x86_64`: ManyLinux platform targeting x86_64 architecture (64-bit) for compatibility with many Linux distributions.
5. `manylinux1_i686`: ManyLinux platform targeting i686 architecture (32-bit) for compatibility with many Linux distributions.
6. `manylinux2014_x86_64`: ManyLinux 2010 platform targeting x86_64 architecture.
7. `manylinux2014_i686`: ManyLinux 2010 platform targeting i686 architecture.
8. `manylinux_2_24_x86_64`: ManyLinux 2.24 platform targeting x86_64 architecture.
9. `manylinux_2_24_i686`: ManyLinux 2.24 platform targeting i686 architecture.
10. `linux_x86_64`: Linux platform targeting x86_64 architecture.
11. `linux_i686`: Linux platform targeting i686 architecture.
12. `linux_armv7l`: Linux platform targeting ARMv7 architecture.
13. `linux_aarch64`: Linux platform targeting ARM64 (AArch64) architecture.
14. `linux_ppc64le`: Linux platform targeting PowerPC 64-bit (little-endian) architecture.

These are some common platform options, and the specific list may change over time as new platforms are supported and older ones become less relevant. To see the full list of available platforms and their corresponding package support on PyPI, you can use the `pip download --platform` command, as previously mentioned.

For my case I was using `debian-buster` For Debian Buster, which is Debian 10, a suitable platform option for many Python packages is `manylinux2010_x86_64`. This platform is designed to provide compatibility with a wide range of Linux distributions, including older distributions like Debian 10 (Buster), by using the manylinux standard.

You can specify the platform when using the `pip download` command as follows:

```
pip download --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 <package-name>
```

This command will download a package compatible with Debian 10 (Buster) and many other Linux distributions that adhere to the manylinux2010 standard. However, not all packages will have specific manylinux2010_x86_64 versions available, so you may want to check the package's availability and compatibility with your specific platform on PyPI.